# Create straight horizontal line

Tags: gimp

Straight lines can be created by holding the shift key.  Is there a way to snap to horizontal (or vertical)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click with the brush, move the cursor holding Ctrl and Shift at the same time and click at the endpoint. The direction is by default limited to discrete values with 15 degrees steps. That includes horizontal and vertical.

Comment: For vertical/horizontal lines, you can also use guides (which often turn out to be useful for other things in the image).

Comment: Yes, this works.  I thought I had tried every key combination...